# How to apply replace-regexp to only a single line in emacs?

Tags: regex, emacs

How do I apply replace-regexp to only a single line in a text buffer in emacs?  For example, I am working in org-mode and would like to apply this regular expression replacement to the currently selected line only, not the entire org-mode text buffer:

```
M-x replace-regexp RET [-]\\{1\\}[ ]\\{1\\} RET RET
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<f1> f replace-regexp RET`:

```
replace-regexp is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
`replace.el'.

(replace-regexp REGEXP TO-STRING &optional DELIMITED START END
BACKWARD)

...

In Transient Mark mode, if the mark is active, operate on the contents
of the region.  Otherwise, operate from point to the end of the buffer.
```

In other words, highlight the line, and call `replace-regexp`.